# Why can't I see Google Play "Staff Picks"?

Tags: google-play-store

I used to see the Staff Picks section in Google Play, both on the website and on my device.

Recently, I can't find it - I can see only the "Editor's Choice", this seems to be the only lists of apps that are featured by Google.

Did they remove it, or is it some sort of bug?

Comment: Looks like it was lost in a redesign. I see a "Play Picks" category, and can still see "Editor's Choice", but no "Staff Picks".

Comment: Where do you see "Play Picks"?

Comment: Right at the top of the home page. It's one of several app groupings I see. Here's a screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/3KFCnIh.png?1

Comment: That's strange. I don't see that on my device... Maybe they show it differently for different countries, etc.

Comment: They absolutely show different content based on country and carrier.